# How to use interceptor to add Headers in Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Our team decide to adopt **Retrofit 2.0** and I'm doing some initial research on it. I'm a newbie to this library.

I'm wondering how to use `interceptor` to add customized headers via **Retrofits 2.0** in our Android app. There are many [tutorials](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-add-custom-request-header/) about using `interceptor` to add headers in Retrofit 1.X, but since the APIs have changed a lot in the latest version, I'm not sure how to adapt those methods in the new version. Also, Retrofit hasn't update its new documentation yet.

For example, in the following codes, how should I implement the `Interceptor` class to add extra headers? Besides, what exactly is the [undocumented `Chain` object](https://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor.Chain.html)? When will the `intercept()` be called?

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            // How to add extra headers?

            return response;
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Make sure your BASE_API_URL ends with `/` and that your API urls don't (`stuff/post/whatever`)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Check this out.

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("appid", "hello")
                .addHeader("deviceplatform", "android")
                .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0")
                .build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

*Kotlin*

```
class HeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("appid", "hello")
                .addHeader("deviceplatform", "android")
                .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0")
                .build()
        )        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! So, this `intercept()` is triggered every time a request is sent from the application? Can we catch the intermediate response for redirect, or we just get the final response?

Comment: This is called for every request, and if I know right, it is because you add it as an interceptor, and not as a network interceptor. I think you can get only the final response here, but there might be a config to allow seeing redirects as redirects that I don't know off the top of my head (there is one for http URL connection too.)

Comment: Just refer to this link: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors , and get the information I need:) Thank you~

Comment: Fyi, you need to use a builder instead of `client.interceptors()`.  This looks like `new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(<Your Interceptor>).build()`

Answer (score 26):

Another alternative from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32963488/1008278)

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("headerKey0", "HeaderVal0")
                .addHeader("headerKey0", "HeaderVal0--NotReplaced/NorUpdated") //new header added
                .build();

        //alternative
        Headers moreHeaders = request.headers().newBuilder()
                .add("headerKey1", "HeaderVal1")
                .add("headerKey2", "HeaderVal2")
                .set("headerKey2", "HeaderVal2--UpdatedHere") // existing header UPDATED if available, else added.
                .add("headerKey3", "HeaderKey3")
                .add("headerLine4 : headerLine4Val") //line with `:`, spaces doesn't matter.
                .removeAll("headerKey3") //Oops, remove this.
                .build();

        request = request.newBuilder().headers(moreHeaders).build();

        /* ##### List of headers ##### */
        // headerKey0: HeaderVal0
        // headerKey0: HeaderVal0--NotReplaced/NorUpdated
        // headerKey1: HeaderVal1
        // headerKey2: HeaderVal2--UpdatedHere
        // headerLine4: headerLine4Val

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! So `request.newBuilder().headers(moreHeaders).build()` will keep the original headers?

Comment: Yes. No headers are removed from request unless [removeAll(String name)](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Headers.Builder.html#removeAll-java.lang.String-) is called.

Comment: Wont' this keep creating new objects?

Answer (score 4):

```
   public class ServiceFactory {  
    public static ApiClient createService(String authToken, String userName, String password) {
            OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(
                            chain -> {
                                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        .headers(getJsonHeader(authToken))
                                        .build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            })
                    .authenticator(getBasicAuthenticator(userName, password))
                    .build();
            return getService(defaultHttpClient);
        }
        private static Headers getJsonHeader(String authToken) {
            Headers.Builder builder = new Headers.Builder();
            builder.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            builder.add("Accept", "application/json");
            if (authToken != null && !authToken.isEmpty()) {
                builder.add("X-MY-Auth", authToken);
            }
            return builder.build();
        }
        private static Authenticator getBasicAuthenticator(final String userName, final String password) {
            return (route, response) -> {
                String credential = Credentials.basic(userName, password);
                return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
            };
        }
          private static ApiClient getService(OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient) {
            return new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(defaultHttpClient)
                    .build()
                    .create(ApiClient.class);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can headers using Interceptors with its built-in methods like this

```
   interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();

            builder.header("Authorization","Bearer "+ LeafPreference.getInstance(context).getString(LeafPreference.TOKEN));

            Request request = builder.method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();
            Log.e("request",request.urlString());
            Log.e("header",request.header("Authorization"));
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to know how do you get *context* at this place?

Comment: @rupinderjeet Probably a `final Context context` in the list of parameters.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Just wanted to point out that we shouldn't have `context` here because this is business logic.

Comment: @rupinderjeet You can have application context here if you want (`context.applicationContext`).

Comment: @MohitAtray Yes, maybe. These days, I have a habit of completely separating all network logic in a different module. This network module is independent of android dependencies. That's why I was being skeptical about using `context` directly here.