# Retrofit 2 - Response body null when response status is 422 (unprocessable entity)

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to make a POST Request in my web server.

However, I can't seem to get the response body when the response status is `422 (unprocessable entity)`. The response body is always `null`.

I want to know if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a workaround for this. Because I'm using the same json in the request with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), and it returns the body normally.

This is the method:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json")
@POST("my_endpoint")
Call<JsonObject> postEntry(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Body JsonObject json);
```

The body is a JsonObject, I'm not serializing like the documentation say. But I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: is your api returning some body in `422` errors?. Did you map in android?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan Yes, as I mentioned in the question, when I use Postman to make the request, it returns the body perfectly. I'm using the same json object in both places.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan And about mapping, yes I did. It actually executes the `onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit)` in Callback with `response.body() == null`.

Comment: @Erick  your request is not completed so you face this issue ..

Comment: @amitsharma Why it's not completed?

Comment: Your Request Body is not completed there must be something missing or something wrong that's by you get status 422 , or can be  bad server request..

Comment: I would recommend intercept your request while sending, with OkHttp interceptor and see if you are sending correct, compare it with Postman's

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, when your server is returning an error code `response.body()` is always `null`. What you are looking for is `response.errorBody()`. A common approach would be something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            response.body(); // do something with this
        } else {
            response.errorBody(); // do something with that
        }
    }
```

If you need something advanced take a look at [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) and [how to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0)

Comment: Thanks.. but my errorBody() is always null too.. I managed to make it work without retrofit. I'm awarding you the bounty because it's going to expire

Comment: Ty. Via the interceptor you can examine what is going on under the hood and see the raw request and response. Anyway I'm glad you found a way :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. My API was working using POSTMAN request but not working from Android retrofit call.

At first I was trying using @Field but it was getting error but later I've tried with @Body and it worked.

Sample Retrofit interface call

```
@POST("api/v1/app/instance")
Call<InstanceResponse> updateTokenValue(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @Body String body);
```

and API calling code is:

```
 Map<String, String> headerMap=new HashMap<>();
        headerMap.put("Accept", "application/json");
        headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headerMap.put("X-Authorization","access_token");

        Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
        fields.put("app_name", "video");
        fields.put("app_version", "2.0.0");
        fields.put("firebase_token", "token");
        fields.put("primary", "1");

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<InstanceResponse> call = apiInterface.updateTokenValue(
                headerMap,new Gson().toJson(fields));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you'll have to convert the response.
Have a look at this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling)

All the steps are already provided in the link above.

For Kotlin users here is the code solution.

**ErrorResponse.kt** (This obviously depends on your error response)

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class ErrorResponse(

@Json(name="name")
val name: String? = null,

@Json(name="message")
val message: String? = null,

@Json(name="errors")
val errors: Errors? = null,

@Json(name="statusCode")
val statusCode: Int? = null
)
```

**ApiFactory.kt** (Let me know if you need the entire code)

```
fun parseError(response: Response<*>): ErrorResponse {
    val converter = ApiFactory.retrofit()
            .responseBodyConverter<ErrorResponse>(
                    ErrorResponse::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0)
            )

    val error: ErrorResponse

    try {
        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody()!!)!!
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return ErrorResponse()
    }

    return error
}
```

and in the **Presenter** (I use MVP)

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        try {
            val response = ApiFactory.apiService.LOGIN(username, password)
                    .await()
            val body = response.body()
            body?.let {
            // Handle success or any other stuff
                if (it.statusCode == 200) {
                    mView.onSuccess(it.data!!)
                }
            } ?:
            // This is the else part where your body is null
            // Here is how you use it.
            // Pass the response for error handling
            mView.showMessage(ApiFactory.parseError(response).message!!)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

And thats how you roll it!
That's All Folks!

Comment: Need the entire code ApiFactory.kt