# How to solve com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity in FormUrlEncoded

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, httpexception

I have this API interface

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@POST("checkout/guest/netspay")
fun getNestPayCheckOut(
   @Field("outlet_id") outLetId: String,
   @Field("order_type") orderType:String,
   @Field("products") products:String,
   @Field("pickup_time") pickUpTime:String,
   @Field("total_price_tax") totalPrice:String,
   @Field("order_note") orderNote:String,
   @Field("name") name:String,
   @Field("email") email:String,
   @Field("phone") phone:String

):Observable<NetsPayCheckOut>
```

This is how I perform the API call

```java
fun getNetsPayGuestCheckOut(
   outletId:String, orderType:String,
   products:String, pickUpTime:String,
   name:String,email:String,
   phone:String, totalPrice:String,
   note:String,
   mNetsCheckOut:MutableLiveData<NetsPayCheckOut>,
   mErrorLD: MutableLiveData<Error>
){
mTheApiNew.getNestPayCheckOut(
   outletId,orderType,
   products,pickUpTime,
   name,email,
   phone,totalPrice,
   note
)
   .subscribeOn(scheduler)
   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(object : Observer<NetsPayCheckOut> {
      override fun onComplete() { }

      override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) { }

      override fun onNext(response: NetsPayCheckOut) {
         if(response.status!!){
            mNetsCheckOut.value= response
         } else {
            mErrorLD.value= ServerError(response.message!!)
            Log.e("checkout","${response.status} and ${response.message}")
         }
      }

      override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
         mErrorLD.value= FailureError(e.message!!)
         Log.e("checkout","${e.message} and ${e.localizedMessage}")
      }

   })
}
```

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSWyv.png)

[Postman header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkY2G.png)

`NetsPayCheckOut` & `NetsPayData` classes:

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class NetsPayCheckOut(
   val code: Int? = null,
   @SerializedName("data")
   val netsPayData: NetsPayData? = null,
   val message: String? = null,
   val status: Boolean? = null
)

data class NetsPayData(
   val secretKey: String? = null,
   val txnReq: String? = null,
   val keyId: String? = null
)
```

But I always receive this error

> com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 422
>   Unprocessable Entity

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814857/retrofit-2-with-only-form-data

Comment: It is not solution for my code.

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 - Response body null when response status is 422 (unprocessable entity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141033/retrofit-2-response-body-null-when-response-status-is-422-unprocessable-entit)

Answer (score 2):

The Exception tells you that your server responded with an HTTP error 422. Which means that your request reached your server correctly but it couldn't be processed correctly.

Based on the Postman screenshot and the Retrofit declaration, I can see that you declare your request `@FormUrlEncoded` but in Postman you send those fields not encoded (the equivalent of FormUrlEncoded in Postman is the "x-www-form-urlencoded" tab). 
Removing the `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation from your `getNestPayCheckOut` should help.

If not, one useful way of debugging such errors is by using a Proxy like https://www.charlesproxy.com/. It will allow you to see the HTTP requests made from your phone/application and compare it with what Postman is sending.

As a side-note, if `@FormUrlEncoded` is indeed what is causing the issue, I would recommend modifying your server so that it accepts only encoded fields: that way you won't get any issues if your fields contain special characters like "=" and "&"