# How to make an API call with retrofit using token?

Tags: android, api, twitter, oauth, retrofit2

Following [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#exercise-using-retrofit-with-oauth-to-request-user-details-from-twitter-in-android) tutorial I manage to get token. How now I use this to token to get tweets from user, for example? 
Where should I place this **token** variable and make API call with retrofit?

```
twitterApi.postCredentials("client_credentials").enqueue(new Callback<OAuthToken>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<OAuthToken> call, Response<OAuthToken> response) {
    token = response.body();  // <---- my token
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<OAuthToken> call, Throwable t) {
    // fail
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add it in all requests using interceptors, as descibed here [How to use interceptor to add Headers in Retrofit 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0)