# Get token from Server Response in JSON

Tags: java, android, model, retrofit, retrofit2

I send a post request to a server via the help of Retrofit but i want to get a value from a token when the server sends a response back. This is how i send my post request and onSuccess i want to receive the token. My problem here is that i don't know to retrieve the token from the server response. Kindly help here.

```
public void loginUser(String userName, String userPassword, Boolean userRememberMe) {

    mAPIService.loginUser(userName, userPassword, userRememberMe).enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Login> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if(response.isSuccess()) {
                //save token here
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to Login");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the response i get from the server

```
{
 "total": 0,
 "data": {
"id": "348680c7-d46b-4adc-9be0-89a1d1a38566",
"username": "0242770336",
"name": "name",
"phoneNumber": "063546345",
"email": "number@gmail.com",
"dateOfBirth": null,
"image": null,
"gender": "",
"idTypeId": null,
"idType": null,
"idNumber": null,
"idExpiryDate": null,
"idVerified": false,
"cityId": null,
"city": null,
"residentialAddress": null,
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"createdAt": "2017-08-14T17:45:16.24Z",
"role": {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "User",
  "privileges": [
    ""
  ]
},
"token": "jNK_DGszYOMEpPOFoRGjuyJ5KX9kaJQKCl3cujlHoXklCS8Ij6b-QBmhv0jVwVC54KcNXkzyM62xpswqcjo9Ajf-n-rWzSaIoiYNglaXhtPspziZ0PcTKzTMAvw8si3A7BlcD98M-IjIxYjxieVYAPWVtcvomWi"
},

"message": "Login Successfull",
"success": true
}
```

This is my Login Model

```
public class Login {

@SerializedName("userName")
@Expose
private String userName;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("rememberMe")
@Expose
private Boolean rememberMe;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Boolean getRememberMe() {
    return rememberMe;
}

public void setRememberMe(Boolean rememberMe) {
    this.rememberMe = rememberMe;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

method 1 :use JsonObject

```
mAPIService.loginUser(userName, userPassword, userRememberMe).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
       if(response.isSuccess()) {
         try {

           String token=response.body().get("data").get("token");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

method 2:
you can use http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ to convert your response to POJO. now add it to your project and let's name it ResponseData.class and get token using getter method by doing  to following changes

```
mAPIService.loginUser(userName, userPassword, userRememberMe).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(response.isSuccess()) {
            //save token here
String token =response.getData().getToken();

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to Login");
    }
});
```

Comment: in the first option i would have an error if the callback is enqueued on the Login Model. What do you suggest i do in this case.

Comment: my request model is different from my response model. Check my updated question.

Comment: Callback<T> takes Response Model as a parameter so cannot use login model there as your response is different than response. what thing you need to change is that your retrofit request should return call<ResponseData>  or  Call<JsonObject> and not call<Login>

Comment: an example of your retrofit request   @POST(Common.Urls.RESET_PASSWORD_API)
Call<JsonObject> loginUser(@Body HashMap<String,String> request);

Comment: Thank you for your answer i was able to retrieve the token.

Comment: how do i add the token as a header to every request i send to the server. I would save the token to sharedPreferences so i can have access to it anytime i need to use it in the retrofit header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Convert the response string into `JSONObject` and then again get the `JSONObject` for data and in data you can find your token object.

```
JSONObject  object  = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject dataObject = object.getJSONObject("data");
String token = dataObject.getString("token");
Log.i("TAG","token is "+token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Use `optBoolean()` method and `optString()` method

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean success = jsonObject.optBoolean("success");
        if (success) {
            JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            String token = data.optString("token");
        } else {
            Log.e("message", "failure");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gson` to convert you `json` to a java POJO class. However if you just want to get the token field you can use it like this:

```
public void onResponse(Response<Login> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(response.isSuccess()) {
             try {
        JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(response.body());
        String token = ob.getJSONObject("data").getString("token");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to first understand that this response is in Json format
you need to first create the Json object from the response you get from server  . for better understanding https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
http://www.json.org/
and code to get that response.

```
try{
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String token = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("token");
}
catch(JSONException e){
e.printstacktrace();
}
```