# How should I put code in Background Thread in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, okhttp, rest

I am using an API which uploads some data to the server, I am deploying this on android application.

I tested APIs using Postman and it works absolutely fine and generated code from postman

login code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("username","abc@abc.com")
  .addFormDataPart("password","E1234567")
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("192.168.1.51/auth/login")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "Koala Admin")
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("Cookie", "session=3d9c1888-e9b0-40b3-958b-71c50538d338")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

create user and upload photo

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("subject_type","1")
  .addFormDataPart("name","jasim")
  .addFormDataPart("start_time","1619496549")
  .addFormDataPart("end_time","1619525349")
  .addFormDataPart("photo","/C:/Users/jasim/Pictures/Camera Roll/WIN_20210422_14_54_39_Pro.jpg",
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
    new File("/C:/Users/jasim/Pictures/Camera Roll/WIN_20210422_14_54_39_Pro.jpg")))
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("192.168.1.51/subject/file")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("Cookie", "session=3d9c1888-e9b0-40b3-958b-71c50538d338")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Now I want to know that how can I put these code in AsyncTask class and make the necessary code in background.

Comment: Why don't you use retrofit?

Comment: i don't know anything about retrofit. can you help me with this code. how to put in background thread. thanks

Comment: You can use the answer by @shmakova

Comment: @Amin I need another help from you. There is cookie header in my api request, every time I have to copy this cookie from postman and paste in my code to make it work. how can I generate cookie in my app and give that value in cookie header?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `enqueue` method instead of `execute` and it will work on the background thread:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
         // handle your response
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
         // handle the failure
    }
});
```

Comment: really? is this method will work like a doInBackground() does?

Comment: It will run on own okttp dispatcher. @JASIMCHOUHAN

Comment: HI @shmakova, I need another help from you. There is cookie header in my api request, every time I have to copy this cookie from postman and paste in my code to make it work. how can I generate cookie in my app and give that value in cookie header?