# how to solve add variable in Retrofit header on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I've tried so many times with different type of initialisation. In this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18vwl.jpg) I use a global variable which already initialise a value. Its too much can anybody help with that type of error

Comment: To add a dynamic header in retrofit, you need to create an interceptor.  This question it was solved on stockoverflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own interceptor and add the token there not on your interface.

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        LoginResponse toc = LoginResponse();
        Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + toc.getToken())
                .build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then add this interceptor in your OkHttpClient and then add that OkHttpClient to your Retrofit.

Answer (score -1):

Header accepts the data in this format

Single example:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
```

Multiple example:

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "User-Agent: Your-App-Name",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
    })
```

In your case the code should be changed to,

```
@Headers({"Authorization: "+ tokenn})
```

Comment: That's not possible, he should create an interceptor to do so. He wants to add dynamic value I'd suppose, in case it's static yes, he can do what you say, but otherwise it's not possible.

Comment: can you help how it could be possible?

Comment: he did not say it's dynamic so I assumed it was needed only for specific api